# Selenium code in Python produces syntax errors

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, syntax, syntax-error

I am getting syntax errors. I tried this first:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(C:\Webdriver)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

And got this:

```
  File "C:/Users/donbr/PycharmProjects/Seleniumtes/Selenium Test.py", line 3
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(C:\Webdriver)
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So I changed it to this because I thought it was asking me to take the `C:` out

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(\Webdriver)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

just for it to say this:

```
  File "C:/Users/donbr/PycharmProjects/Seleniumtes/Selenium Test.py", line 3
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(\Webdriver)
                                        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

What does that mean? Why is it pointing to the bracket like it isn't supposed to be there? How is that an unexpected character?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Looks like you are not enclosing `"C:\Webdriver"` in quotes - the value needs to be a string.

Comment: @Ashley: I don't know Python, but it looks like the errors use a forward slash in paths. If a backslash is used, might that be mistaken for a control character? I wonder if "C:/Webdriver" is supported?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass the complete path to chrome web driver as shown below.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(<complete path to chrome web driver executable>) 
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```